# Run an SSIS package in tSQLt

Tags: sql, ssis, integration-testing, ssis-2012, tsqlt

I'm trying to write an SSIS integration test using tSQLt. I've set up my tables and have my `AssertEqualsTable` at the end of the test but the package I call doesn't seem to run. I'm using the following in my tSQLt test:

```
declare @execution_id BIGINT
    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
        @package_name=N'$PackageName$', 
        @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, 
        @folder_name=N'$FolderName$', 
        @project_name=N'$ProjectName$', 
        @use32bitruntime=False, 
        @reference_id=30058

SELECT @execution_id

DECLARE @var0 SMALLINT = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
    @execution_id,  
    @object_type=50, 
    @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL', 
    @parameter_value=@var0

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
```

Comment: I suggest you split this issue into two : 1. Does the assert work as expected?; 2. Does the T-SQL alone start the package as expected? Establish that and post back. It might have nothing to do with SSIS or it might have nothing to do with tSQLt

Comment: One thing to remember is that tSQLt tests run in their own transaction - I am not sure what impact that will have on the call to  [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] et al

Comment: I'm going through exactly the same issue.  First thing I tried was adding the following: EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
    @execution_id,  
    @object_type=50, 
    @parameter_name=N'SYNCHRONIZED', 
    @parameter_value=1  this makes the execution engine wait for the SSIS package to complete before moving onto the Assert statement.  This worked for me once, but it doesn't now so it would be interesting to see what success you have with it